# generic_inlineformset_factory do not show GenericForeignKey into template

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

In my Django-1.5.1 application, I have the following situation:

- **models.py**

  ```
  class Cod(models.Model):
      name = models.SlugField()
      user = models.ForeignKey(User)

  class Steps(models.Model):
      number = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
      cod = models.ForeignKey(Cod, related_name='cod')
      step_cod = models.ForeignKey(Cod, null=True, related_name='step_cod')
      content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
      object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
      content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey()
  ```
- **forms.py**

  ```
  class StepsForm(ModelForm):
      class Meta:
         model = Steps
  ```
- **views.py**

  ```
  def getSteps(request):
      cod_id = 1
      steps = Steps.objects.filter(cod=cod_id).order_by('number')
      StepFormset = generic_inlineformset_factory(Steps, form=StepsForm, can_delete=False)
      step_formset = StepFormset(queryset=steps)
      for step in steps:
          print step.content_object
      print "-------------------------"
      for form in step_formset:
          print form.instance
      print "-------------------------"
      for form in step_formset:
          print form.instance.content_object

      return render_to_response('tss/base_codForm.html',
                               {'step_formset': step_formset},
                                context_instance=RequestContext(request))
  ```
- **base_codForm.html**

  ```
  {% for form in step_formset %}
      {{ form }}
  {% endfor %}
  ```

Looking at the for loops output inside **views.py**, I get the correct related objects, the steps instances inside my formset, but content_object inside form instances are missing:

```
ObjectAggregate object
ObjectGroup object
ObjectRefine object
ObjectSizeCheck object
-------------------------
Steps object
Steps object
Steps object
-------------------------
None
None
None
```

Indeed my template renders only number, cod and step_cod fields:

```
<tr>
    <th><label for="id_tss-steps-content_type-object_id-0-number">Number:</label></th>
    <td><input id="id_tss-steps-content_type-object_id-0-number" name="tss-steps-content_type-object_id-0-number" type="text" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th><label for="id_tss-steps-content_type-object_id-0-cod">Cod:</label></th>
    <td>
        <select id="id_tss-steps-content_type-object_id-0-cod" name="tss-steps-content_type-object_id-0-cod">
            <option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>
            <option value="1">Cod object</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th><label for="id_tss-steps-content_type-object_id-0-step_cod">Step cod:</label></th>
    <td>
        <select id="id_tss-steps-content_type-object_id-0-step_cod" name="tss-steps-content_type-object_id-0-step_cod">
            <option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>
            <option value="1">Cod object</option>
        </select>
        <input id="id_tss-steps-content_type-object_id-0-id" name="tss-steps-content_type-object_id-0-id" type="hidden" />
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <th><label for="id_tss-steps-content_type-object_id-1-number">Number:</label></th>
    <td><input id="id_tss-steps-content_type-object_id-1-number" name="tss-steps-content_type-object_id-1-number" type="text" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th><label for="id_tss-steps-content_type-object_id-1-cod">Cod:</label></th>
    <td>
        <select id="id_tss-steps-content_type-object_id-1-cod" name="tss-steps-content_type-object_id-1-cod">
            <option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>
            <option value="1">Cod object</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th><label for="id_tss-steps-content_type-object_id-1-step_cod">Step cod:</label></th>
    <td>
        <select id="id_tss-steps-content_type-object_id-1-step_cod" name="tss-steps-content_type-object_id-1-step_cod">
            <option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>
            <option value="1">Cod object</option>
        </select>
        <input id="id_tss-steps-content_type-object_id-1-id" name="tss-steps-content_type-object_id-1-id" type="hidden" />
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <th><label for="id_tss-steps-content_type-object_id-2-number">Number:</label></th>
    <td><input id="id_tss-steps-content_type-object_id-2-number" name="tss-steps-content_type-object_id-2-number" type="text" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th><label for="id_tss-steps-content_type-object_id-2-cod">Cod:</label></th>
    <td>
        <select id="id_tss-steps-content_type-object_id-2-cod" name="tss-steps-content_type-object_id-2-cod">
            <option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>
            <option value="1">Cod object</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th><label for="id_tss-steps-content_type-object_id-2-step_cod">Step cod:</label></th>
    <td>
        <select id="id_tss-steps-content_type-object_id-2-step_cod" name="tss-steps-content_type-object_id-2-step_cod">
            <option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>
            <option value="1">Cod object</option>
        </select>
        <input id="id_tss-steps-content_type-object_id-2-id" name="tss-steps-content_type-object_id-2-id" type="hidden" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

What am I missing? How to get related generic objects inside my formset?
Thank you.

Comment: Do you want the fields can be edited or only read?

Comment: Only read, but if I cannot access I get stopped a step before that...

Answer (score -1):

It seems `models.py` should be:

> ```
> class Steps(models.Model):
>     ...
>     content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
>     object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
>     content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
> ```

Besides you can look on a [this decision](http://adamalton.co.uk/blog/displaying-django-genericforeignkey-as-single-form-field/)

Comment: No, as reported [in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#id1) (class GenericForeignKey, point 3) `content_type` and `object_id` are the defaults, so they can be omitted. Thanks anyway for the link!